# Referencing the Object from its method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created an object `Chart` containing the method `redraw()`. Because the context of `this` from within `redraw()` has been changed from the `Chart` object to a DOM element, I cannot access properties (eg: `this.data`) of the object `Chart`.

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/a4tbG/1/

*Try dragging around the grey box to trigger `redraw()`*

**Question:** How can I access the parent object `chart.data` from the function `chart.redraw`?

```
chart = new Chart();
chart.init();



function Chart() {

    this.data = [1, 2, 3];

    this.init = function () {
        var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .on("zoom", this.redraw);

        d3.select('#chart')
            .append('svg:svg')
            .attr('width', 300)
            .attr('height', 300)
            .call(zoom);
    }

    this.redraw = function () {
        console.log(this);    // Output the DOM element #chart svg. How do you access the object?
        console.log(this.data); 
    }

}
```

Comment: use `bind()` as in dystroy's answer or use `$.proxy(this.redraw,this)` to support older browsers

Comment: @A.Wolff Browsers without bind don't support canvas or svg.

Comment: The close votes here look random...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to ensure the callback is called with the right context. Change

```
.on("zoom", this.redraw);
```

to

```
.on("zoom", this.redraw.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the reference of **this** variable in some other variable and then used it.

```
chart = new Chart();
chart.init();


function Chart() {

    this.data = [1, 2, 3];
    var $this=this;
    this.init = function () {
        var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .on("zoom", $this.redraw);

        d3.select('#chart')
            .append('svg:svg')
            .attr('width', 300)
            .attr('height', 300)
            .call(zoom);
    }

    this.redraw = function () {
            // Output the DOM element #chart svg. How do you access the object?
        console.log($this.data); 
    }

}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a4tbG/5/)